# How to create a jQuery validation to Django environment?

Tags: html, jquery, django

I've been looking for a solution for this problem of mine but I didn't find a final solution because they don't even work/run on the project I am doing. I found some stuff abou jQuery validation plugin and followed a tutorial in https://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/ but it doesn't work for the project I am doing. I would like some help!

form.html

```
<head>
    <title>Sign In Page</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'cursoOnline/logInSignIn.css' %}"/>
    <script src="{% static 'validation.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <image src="{% static 'cursoOnline/Books.jpg' %}" height="730"></image>
    <div>
        <form action=""  name="registration" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            </br></br>
            Nome:<input type="text" name="nome"/></br>
            Senha:<input type="text" name="senha"/></br></br>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Sign in">
        </form>
         <a href="{% url 'cursoOnline:index' %}">Back to Homepage</a>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

validation.js

```
$(validation() {
    $("form[name='registration']").validate({
        rules: {
            nome: "required",
            senha: "required",
            },
            nome: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            }
            senha: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        messages: {
            nome: {
                required: "Please enter your name"
                minlength: "Your name must be at least 3 characters long"
            },
            senha: {
                required: "Please enter your password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
        },
        submitHandler: validation(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is your specific problem here? Does your code not run? If so, can you provide a traceback and your understanding of why not? Your JavaScript sample has a syntax error.

Comment: Like, this is for creating a website for a project and when I try creating an account there, it simply doesn't pop up the errors like it is supposed to. Can you tell me what syntax error on JavaScript, if you don't mind?

Comment: Your syntax error is here: `$(validation() {`. That should be `$(function() {`. Aside from that, there's no way I can help you without more information. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What more information do you need?

Comment: What is your *specific* problem here? Does your code not run? If so, can you provide a traceback and your understanding of why not? Does your code run but do something unexpected? If so, what does it do and how does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: The code runs but the supposed messages I coded don't appear on the screen. There are no errors on the code or else Pycharm would say it.